# Crear página de atributos

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-api

espero que se encuentren muy bien.

Acudo a la ayuda de esta excelente comunidad, porque tengo un problema que me está rondando desde hace un buen tiempo y no he podido encontrar solución.

Tengo una [tienda en woocommerce](https://mandolina.co/), con más de 1000 productos. Yo no inicie el proyecto, lo hizo otro colega y en este momento existe una problemática fuerte.

Resulta que el anterior desarrollador, creó una atributo llamado "marcas", en la cual se le asignaba una marca diferente a cada producto. Pero en este momento se desea listar los productos de todas las marcas y que se descrimine por cada una.

En este momento, por medio de ubermenu, se logró acceder a cada página de la marca por medio del menú "Marcas". "ver imagen"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero se quiere hacer una página en la que se pueda acceder a todas las marcas, y por medio de bullets se pueda acceder a cada marca, de la misma forma en que están todas las categorías de producto de la tienda. "por ejemplo la categoría cocción"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber si existe alguna forma, de convertir un atributo a una categoría y cada elemento del atributo en una subcategoría. O, si existe una manera de poder listar todos los productos del atributo "marcas" en una página, ya que aún no encuentro la forma de lograrlo. Por favor, una recomendación que quiero hacer es que toda la ayuda sea en código, no quiero plugins para lograrlo.

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. Lo agradezco infinitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en:

> Pero en este momento se desea listar los productos de todas las marcas y que se descrimine por cada una. O, si existe una manera de poder listar todos los productos del atributo "marcas" en una página

Te pregunto, has visto el link de la tienda de tu propia web?? https://mandolina.co/tienda/

En esa pagina tienes lo que quieres, todos tus productos indiferentemente de marcas.  Luego puedes editar esa pagina con algunos filtros o lo que quieras.

Por cierto, la "tienda" de tu web no esta listada por ningún lado.